# Xamarin Android Material Calendar View update today selection

Tags: android, xamarin.android, calendar, material-design

If my app is running more than 1 day, today's selection in material calendar view is not updating to next day. I've trying to do this on resume method:

```
protected override void OnResume()
{
    Java.Util.Date today = DateTime.Now.GetJavaDate();
    CalendarDay calendarDay = new CalendarDay(today);
    fragmentMain.fragmentCalendar.CalendarControl.SetCurrentDate(calendarDay, true);
    base.OnResume();
}
```

but this code doesn't update today's selection in calendar.

Comment: Does your SetCurrentDate accept only Java Date?

Comment: @G.hakim do you mean method's overloads?

Comment: The method parameter for SetCurrentDate